# AWS Java SDK 2 S3 copy object

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk-2.x

In the version 1 SDK, making a copy request was straightforward with:

```
new CopyObjectRequest(sourceBucket, sourceKey, destinationBucket, destinationKey)
```

In the version 2 SDK, the `Builder` for `CopyObjectRequest` does not have a clear way to set the source vs destination. There is a `copySource(copySource)` method which accepts a full path, but there is no obvious way to set the destination bucket or destination key or to set the source bucket and source key normally (without building a full path and dealing with URL encoding).

Their [new S3 examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html) simply leave out how the new copy works and their [JavaDoc for `CopyObjectRequest`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/CopyObjectRequest.html) has no real information for this.

Comment: Note: Sometime after this was originally asked, AWS updated their S3 examples with an example of how the copy works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a pretty good example here on Github: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/CopyObject.java

Comment: It seems like their example isn't fully correct since their [documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/CopyObjectRequest.Builder.html#copySource-java.lang.String-) mentions the source value "must be URL-encoded", but they aren't encoding it here. Seems like it would fail if there are special characters in the key name.

Comment: Note: AWS eventually updated their example: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/commit/ca698d2407e23351215de3cecadddbda8d1a137e#diff-04a531169b97e0279b78950d7d4f96b3

Comment: Correct URL for updated example: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/CopyObject.java

Answer (score 2):

It follows the builder pattern now, so read the documentation for the [CopyObjectRequest.Builder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/CopyObjectRequest.Builder.html) for more details.

Here's an example as of `'AWS SDK for Java' v2.17.166`:

```java
  s3.copyObject(
    CopyObjectRequest.builder()
      .sourceBucket(SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME)
      .sourceKey(SOURCE_KEY)
      .destinationBucket(DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME)
      .destinationKey(DESTINATION_KEY)
      .build()
  );
```

Comment: Their documentation wasn't helpful because they don't specify anywhere that `bucket` and `key` are intended for the destination values. I guess we are supposed to infer this since they have `copySource` with "source" in the name, but no methods with "destination" in the name. Seems a lot less clear than the old way though.

Comment: The `bucket` and `key` method have both been deprecated:  https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/CopyObjectRequest.Builder.html

Comment: @james.garriss I believe they were not deprecated at the time this was answered a year and a half ago. Thanks for letting me know, I've updated the answer.

Comment: And now (at least in 2.17.165 version of AWS SDK for Java)...copySource(String) has been deprecated. Use `CopyObjectRequest.builder().sourceBucket(SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME).sourceKey(SOURCE_KEY).destinationBucket(DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME).destinationKey(DESTINATION_KEY).build()`

Comment: @Camile Thank you, I've updated the answer to follow the API changes.

Answer (score 0):

At least in 2.17.165 version of AWS SDK for Java, copySource(String) has been deprecated.

Use

```
CopyObjectRequest.builder()
.sourceBucket(SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME)
.sourceKey(SOURCE_KEY)
.destinationBucket(DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME)
.destinationKey(DESTINATION_KEY)
.build()
```